# @font-face doesn't work on some computers

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, webfonts

I'm using @font-face in my project for loading a specific webfont ("Amsi Pro"). The main problem is that it works on most of the computers I tested, but not on all (On those where it didn't work other websites with @font-face still worked).

Is there anything I've missed, or any server settings to set that will give me full support?

Some information of a PC where @font-face doesn't work:
[whatsmybrowser.org/b/Q2TJ80F](http://whatsmybrowser.org/b/Q2TJ80F)

Live Preview:
[christlicher-gesundheitskongress.de](http://www.christlicher-gesundheitskongress.de/aboutus.html)

CSS:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'AmsiPro';
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('../webfonts/2E508B_0_0.eot');
  src: url('../webfonts/2E508B_0_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('../webfonts/2E508B_0_0.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('../webfonts/2E508B_0_0.woff') format('woff'),
       url('../webfonts/2E508B_0_0.ttf') format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'AmsiPro';
  font-weight: 600;
  src: url('../webfonts/2E508B_1_0.eot');
  src: url('../webfonts/2E508B_1_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('../webfonts/2E508B_1_0.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('../webfonts/2E508B_1_0.woff') format('woff'),
       url('../webfonts/2E508B_1_0.ttf') format('truetype');
}

html,body {
    font-family: 'AmsiPro', Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: practical question: instead of a link to a website, can you just mention the OS/browser combination you were using directly in the post, and what the developer console for that browser said was happening when you loaded the page? (e.g. if it had errors, were they font related? were there 404s, warnings on the CSS, etc?)

Comment: Also, note that FF38 is no longer the current version (the reason FF and Chrome have a new release every 6 weeks is exactly to fix bugs like this). We're on FF 40 at the time of this comment: is this still happening on FF 40 for you?

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 64bit and FF 38.0.5 and it seems like this version is the newest for Germany. I just checked for updates but FF says 38.0.5 is the current

Comment: new versions are rolled out world wide - if you go to the "hamburger" menu, then to the small (?) icon in the lower right of the menu, then click the German equivalent of "about firefox", it should recheck and find that the latest version is 40.0.2

Comment: This is what I did and FF says 38.0.5 is the current version

Comment: your FF might be broken O_o https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/all lists 40.0.2 as latest for German locales, like everyone else. Did you turn off autoupdating in about:config somehow?

Comment: I don't think so. Even the version on my MacBook Pro is 39 and FF says its the current (after checking Firefox > About Firefox). There always comes an update but mostly a little bit later.
And I didn't changed anything in about:config

Answer (score 1):

Even though it seems that Firefox 38 [should support @font-face](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fontface), there may be a partial use issue. Try using an app like [Font-Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) to develop an SVG of your font and then reorder your @font-face like so:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
   url('webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
   url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
   url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
   url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Per [this source](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/), it should maximize the amount of support your font has.

Hope this helped!

Comment: that compound rule hasn't made sense for quite a few browser versions now. font-face has [broad support](http://caniuse.com/#search=font-face), and [everything including IE](http://caniuse.com/#search=WOFF) supports `WOFF`, so you really don't need more than a single source.

Comment: Right Mike, I sourced the compatibility though I didn't know that about woff so thank you for sharing. As I said I don't get why @ font-face isn't working in Firefox 38, as we can see by the browser compatibility check. So the best I can think of is to try another method of rendering the @ font-face to get it to work right. +1 on your question comment for asking for more info